# Core image minimal fails

Tags: yocto

I'm building a Yocto minimal image on Opensuse Tumbleweed using `bitbake core-image-minimal` and I am getting the error 
`qemu-native/4.1.0-r0/qemu-4.1.0/linux-user/syscall.c:7657: undefined reference to 'stime'
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Some googling turns up some known bugs referencing this, and it seems to be caused by glibc taking out stime from time.h in a newer version.

Source:
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Glibc_2.31_porting_notes/stime_removal

So my question is how do I fix this? I would like to avoid rolling back the c library if possible but if there are no other options I guess I don't have a choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What oe-core version are you using? Is it zeus? I think it's already fixed in just released dunfell.

See oe-core commit 2cca75155baec8358939e2aae822e256bed4cfe0

Comment: I was able to reproduce this in Ubuntu 20.04 and already asked for backport: https://lists.openembedded.org/g/openembedded-core/topic/zeus_patch_qemu_replace/73197049?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,73197049

Comment: This is the answer for me. My dumbass didn't realize there was a new version.